# Trying to get a string from a list input

Tags: python

So I am given a list-

```
combos=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
```

and a dictionary

```
d={0:2,1:2}
sum = 4
```

I want the output to be-

```
a=["yynn","yyyy","nnyy"]
```

The length of each string in the output remains the same and is represented by sum which is computed by adding all the values in d.

So,each index in combos represents a possible combo. 
Combo 0 is `[0,0]`. We look at the dictionary and see that 0 has a length 2. So the combo for group 0 is `"yy"`.
Although 0 repeats twice, since the number isn't unique, its just added to the string once. And "n" is added to the rest of the length of the string.

so `s="yynn"` as 1 has a length 2 and is not in the combo.
Similarly, combo 1 is [0,1] 
so we look at d and see that 0 has a length 2 and so does 1,
so `s="yyyy"`
These are then appended to a list.
What I have tried so far:

```
a=[]
s=""
for i in range(len(combos)):
    for j in range(len(combos[i])):
        if new[i][j] in d:
            s+="y"
        else:
            s+="n"
```

Comment: I don't follow the pattern at all

Comment: What exactly? We just look at the possible combos and add"y" to the string at the given indexes

Comment: Any of it. I've read it 4 times now and I don't get it. It's possibly not helped by both values in the dict being `2`

Comment: @sugu, *We look at the dictionary and see that 0 has a length 2 so s="yynn"* - this sounds clear for you but not for others. Put more clarifications

Comment: Please try to explain it better. Your problem is not really understandable right now. The first "combo" is `[0, 0]`, right? What is the exact connection between each of the zeros and the resulting `yynn`? And for the other two. Do sublists in `combos` always contain two elements? And are the numbers always `0` or `1`, or can there be other numbers?

Comment: I am sorry I will rephrase it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
combos=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
d={0:2,1:2}

sorted_keys, out = sorted(d.keys()), []
for c in combos:
    s, items_in_combo = '', set(c)
    for k in sorted_keys:
        if k not in items_in_combo:
            s += 'n' * d[k]
        else:
            s += 'y' * d[k]
    out.append(s)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['yynn', 'yyyy', 'nnyy']
```